# How to dynamically create new objects in a loop

Tags: javascript

I'm following a JS course and I was wondering if it was possible to create new variables in loops?

My example:

**JavaScript**

```
var films = {
  init: function (titre, annee, real) {
    this.titre = titre;
    this.annee = annee;
    this.real = real;
  },
  decrire: function () {
    var description = this.titre + "(" + this.annee + ")" + ", réalisé par " + this.real;
    return description;
  }
};



for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var film = Object.create(films);
  film = prompt("Film:");
  annee = prompt("année");
  real = prompt("real");
}

films.forEach(function (film) {
  console.log(decrire());
}
```

I would like to create new objects at each turn of the loop and ask people for titles, years, and realisators, finally print it in the console.
But I get something like this for my last line of code:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

And my webpage doesn't ask me to put a new movie =/ I don't know how to figure this out.
Where could I find some documentation about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `)` to close `forEach` function. Should be

```
films.forEach(function (film){
  console.log(decrire());
});
```

**EDIT:** Your code contains several other errors too. Sorry for ignoring.

Yes, you can create new variables in loops.
I have fixed your code like you probably wanted it to work. See code comments.

```
// It's recommened to use Capitalized name for a "class" like here.
// This is NOT very good Javascript, but it works.
var Film = {
  init: function (titre, annee, real) {
    this.titre = titre;
    this.annee = annee;
    this.real = real;
  },
  decrire: function () {
    var description = this.titre + "(" + this.annee + ")" + ", réalisé par " + this.real;
    return description;
  }
};

// Initial array of films
var films = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  var film = Object.create(Film);

  // Save user inputs
  var titre = prompt("Film:");
  var annee = prompt("année");
  var real = prompt("real");

  // Run init function for created 
  film.init(titre, annee, real);

  // Save it to array of films
  films.push(film);
}

films.forEach(function (film) {
  // Run decrire() of each film in the array
  console.log(film.decrire());
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! =)

Comment: But I don't understand something. If we create the same object at each turn of the loop: 'film'. Why the next turn doesn't over write the previous object?:
turn 1: film=Split, 2017,...
turn 1: film=inside out, 2016, ....
For me the loop create always the same object =/ Or does it automatically film1, film2, etc?

Answer (score 0):

you're not closing your forEach:

```
films.forEach(  function (film){
    console.log(   decrire()   );
} );
```

EDIT: admitted, it only answer the error, not the rest of the question